# Permutation of partitions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

Let $N \subset \mathbb N$ and $\Pi$ the set of partitions of $N$.
I want to define a permutation such that the partition $\pi \in \Pi$ is identical with $\pi' \in \Pi$ up to a permutation $p : N \to N$ of the index $i \in N$.

**Exmaple**
Consider $N = \{1,2,3\}$ and $\pi = \{\{1\},\{2,3\}\}$. The permutation $p(N) = \{2,3,1\}$ shall result in $\pi' = \{\{2\},\{3,1\}\}$. Does there exist a common definition or how would you define $\pi'$ from $p$?

**Edit**
With respect to the comment one may defines $\rho : \Pi \to \Pi$ by $\rho(\pi) := \{\{p(i)\}_{i \in S} \mid S \in \pi\}$. Reconsdering the example $\pi = \{\{1\},\{2,3\}\}$ and $p(\{1,2,3\}) = \{2,3,1\}$ yields 
\begin{align}
\rho(\pi)& = \{\{p(i)\}_{i \in \{1\}}, \{p(i)\}_{i \in \{2,3\}}\}\\
& = \{\{p(1)\}, \{p(2),p(3)\}\\
& = \{\{2\},\{3,1\}\}\\
& = \pi'.
\end{align}

Is the definition sound?

Comment: What do you mean by identical up to a permutation of index $i\in N$? For your example, assuming $p(1)=2,p(2)=3,$ and $p(3)=1$, does that mean $\pi'=\{\{2\},\{3,1\}\}=\{\{p(1)\},\{p(2),p(3)\}\}$ is identical with $\pi$ up to the fixed permutation $p$ of index $3$?

Comment: Yes that was the definition I had in mind, and then $\rho$ is a permutation since $\rho$ looks to be injective, and is onto by $p^{-1}$.  And it seems $N$ can be any set.